# LINQ question - How to make where != value

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table "Friends" with the ID of the logged user and his/her friend's IDs.

The result I get with this SQL query

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Nickname 
FROM UserSet as u, FriendsSet as f
WHERE u.ID=f.FriendID
ORDER BY u.Nickname
```

Is

```
| ID | Nickname |
-----------------
| 16 | rugardini|
| 17 |   Teste  |
```

"rugardini" is my current user, it appears because in a friendship relation "Teste" is my friend and I'm his friend too, but in my list of friends I don't want my own user appears.

So I did the following query excluding my own ID (16)

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Nickname 
FROM UserSet as u, FriendsSet as f
WHERE u.ID=f.FriendID and u.ID != 16
ORDER BY u.Nickname
```

I have 2 questions:

1) Is this the best way of doing this selection?
2) How to convert this SQL query to LINQ?

Comment: Your query doesn't currently have anything to identify the current user. Please post more details of your table structure - I don't think you've really given us enough information at the moment.

Comment: Create an instance of the current user and replace `16` with it.

Answer (score 3):

about 2): linq for your second query should look like this:

```
from u in db.UserSet, f in db.FieldsSet
where u.ID=f.FriendID && u.ID != 16
orderby u.Nickname
select u.ID, u.Nickname
```

Comment: Thank you mishau, your answer were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I could perform my query only like this:

```
var friends = (from u in db.UserSets
               join f in db.FriendsSets
               on u.ID equals f.FriendID
               where u.ID != userID
               orderby u.Nickname
               select new Friends { ID = u.ID, Nickname = u.Nickname }).ToList();
```

With a class in my controller like this:

```
public class Friends
{
    public int ID;
    public string Nickname;
}
```

And a loop in my view like this:

```
<ul>
@foreach (dynamic item in ViewBag.Friends)
{
    <li>@item.Nickname @Html.ActionLink("Amigo", "Index", new { id = item.ID })</li>
}
</ul>
```

Thank you for all those who answered my question =)